# How to manage CORS policy properly in express?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I am trying to allow access from everywhere.

I have tried using app middleware:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  next();
});
```

I have tried using it in the route:

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
var login   = req.body;
var sess    = req.session;

if (!login.email && !login.pwd){    
    return res.status(401);
}
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", '*');
.... more code here
```

Both do not work. I keep getting an error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Further down the server, we use similar code for another route, which works:

```
app.post('/questar',function(req,res){
//allow xhr post from retireup domains
var cors = {
    origin: "https://www.website.com";
};
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", cors.origin);
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.type('application/json');
```

I cannot tell the difference between the code, but only one set works. Any ideas why? This seems like an issue that shouldn't be so complicated. Thanks

Comment: try cors npm module ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**MDN** has a very short explanation on how a server should respond to a [Preflight Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

You handle CORS preflight requests by handling the HTTP OPTIONS method (just like you would handle GET and POST methods) **before** handling other request methods on the same route:

```
app.options('/login', ...);
app.get('/login'. ...);
app.post('/login'. ...);
```

In your case, it might be as simple as changing your `app.use()` call to `app.options()`, passing the route as the first argument, setting the appropriate headers, then ending the response:

```
app.options('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  res.end();
});
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 26):

After applying "cors" middleware. You should be passed "http://" before "localhost:". in url send to by Axios like this:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/getData")
.then(function (response) {
this.items= response.data;
}).catch(function (error) {
console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: This answer saved me! forgot to add http://

Answer (score 10):

Configure the CORS stuff before your routes, not inside them.

Here, like this (from [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

I always configure it like this in my Express+Angular apps and it works just fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be highlighted, I was configuring my cors before the routes. Thanks alot, you saved me a lot of debug :D

Answer (score 6):

First install, the "cors" package from npm: `npm i -S cors`

Then enable it in your express server.

```
var express = require('express'),
  cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

...
```

Comment: Yes, do `cors({origin: true})` instead of just `cors()`

Answer (score 3):

Following some standard node projects out there, below CORS configuration worked for me always. It requires the npm package 'cors'. **Note:** Origin * means enabling responses to any origin and replies with status code 200. If this needs to be limited to one domain, update the origin accordingly. Ex: [origin: 'http://exampleui.com']

```
var cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  }
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to whitelist the domains name to avoid getting cors error messages.

There is a plugin called **[cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)**, installed it into your project using this command

```
npm i cors
```

after installing use this code to remove the cors related errors form your project.

```
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOption = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:80']
}

app.use(cors(corsOption));
```

In the `origin` section you can pass any domain to whitelist it. If you want to whitelist all the domain names, instead of passing the the urls array. you can pass `'*'` over there.

Example : `origin: '*'`

credentials: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials CORS header. Set to true to pass the header, otherwise it is omitted.

Comment: `credentials` has nothing to do with request headers

Answer (score 0):

Following other's answers, this worked for me:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://myDomain:8080');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Accept');
```

Answer (score 0):

Still got stuck with this:

```
app.use(cors());
```

or this:

```
app.use(cors(
    origin: '*'
));
```

You should try this:

```
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: true
}));
```

Note: origin: '*' not this!!! and with credentials: true